# Why cookie request is null return in mvc controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My login methot, 
A cookie incoming data is put,

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        RepairService.EmployeeServiceClient srv = new RepairService.EmployeeServiceClient();
        var CurrentEmployee = await Task.Run(() => srv.LoginEmployee(username, password));

        if (CurrentEmployee != null)
        {
            var model = new EmployeeDetail
            {
                EmloyeeId = CurrentEmployee.EmployeeId,
                //...//
            };

            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("userCookie");
            cookie.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return Json(model);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Json(null);
    }

    return Json(false);
}
```

So you can control when users login cookie is not empty.

```
public ActionResult IsLoggedIn()
{
    return Json(Request.Cookies["userCookie"] != null && Request.Cookies["userCookie"].Value != "");
}
```

When I call to get the value of this method Request is null. Where can I make mistakes ?

```
public ActionResult GetCurrentUser()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["userCookie"] != null && Request.Cookies["userCookie"].Value == "Test")
    {
        var employee = (EmployeeDetail)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.Cookies["userCookie"].Value);

        return Json(employee);
    }        

    return Json(false);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're doing your Auth verification in the wrong way. You should not create an Action in your Controller responsible for that. You must create an ActionFilter, and decorate your Actions or your Controller's, or even register this filter globally to verify this for every request. For example:

**ActionFilter**

```
public class AuthorizedFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{   
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Do your logic here
        var cookieValue = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["userCookie"]).FirstOrDefault();

        if(cookieValue != null)
            return;

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                            {"controller", "Home"},
                            {"action", "Login"},
                        });
    }
}
```

**Controller**

You could use at Controller Level, wich means, it will apply to all Actions

```
[AuthorizedFilter]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Or you could use at Action level

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [AuthorizedFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```